# How to get HTML snippet to toggle consistently?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to toggle between two different html snippets (which includes a font-awesome icon). It's only recognizing the first toggle but won't toggle back to its original text.

https://jsfiddle.net/jnqbxLgs/1/

HTML

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="toggle-list">
   Hide list <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
  </div>
</a>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(".toggle-list").on("click", function() {
    var updateText = $(this).find(".toggle-list");
    updateText.text(updateText.html() == 'Hide List <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>'
  ? 'Show List <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>'
  : 'Hide List <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>'
  );   

  console.log("Toggle the list");

  $("ul").toggle();

    $("i.fa").addClass("fa-hover");

});
```

When the "Hide List" anchor is clicked, the list would hide and the text in the anchor should be replaced with "Show List" with the font-awesome icon pointing downwards.

When the "Show List" anchor is clicked, the list would show, and the text should say "Hide List" with the font awesome icon pointing upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could convert the if statement to a ternary as in your version, but this should suit your needs for now

```
$(".toggle-list").on("click", function() {

    console.log("Toggle the list");
    $("ul").toggle();

    var toggletext = $(".toggle-list").text();

    if (toggletext.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf("hide list") >= 0) {
        $(".toggle-list").html('Show List <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>');
    } else {
        $(".toggle-list").html('Hide List <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>');
    }

});
```

Comment: this only works upon the first two clicks (from Hide to Show, and Show to Hide). Is there a way to make it loop?

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with the if statement. It's looking for some specific text, so it would be easy for there to be a bug on that line. Do you know how to debug javascript in your browser console? If so, set a break point on the if statement, you'll be able to see the value of 'toggletext' and see if that will match what we're looking for in the if statement.